# Careers showing incorrect results for country based location search

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, search

When performing a location based search for "UK", careers is only returning a single result, whereas a search for "London" returns 29 results.

Answer (score 3):

This should be resolved. We had some spurious data in the cache, which we've cleared. Thanks for the heads-up.